# Elasticsearch - OR in term conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I need little help with transfering mysql query to ES. The query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM `xyz` WHERE visibility IN (1,2) AND (active=0 OR (active=1 AND finished=1)
```

It's easy, to make **only** AND conditions, but how to mix AND with OR in ***term***?

```
"query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [{
          "terms" : { "visibility" : ["1", "2"] }
      }, {
          "term" : { "active" : "1" } 
      }, {
          "term" : { "active" : "0", "finished" : "1" } // OR
      },]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this by nesting a `bool/should` and `bool/filter` query inside the main `bool/filter` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "visibility": [
              "1",
              "2"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "active": "0"
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "filter": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "active": "1"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "finished": "1"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```